# Error 4996 'kbhit': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated.

Tags: c++

I am using the `kbhit` method on my code. Currently, when i compile my c++ code its showing me this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'kbhit': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _kbhit.
```

This is my partial c++ code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
            /* enable leaving of endless loop if running under windows, */
            /* necessary to return handles and close driver */


            /* Do I/O Data exchange until a key is hit */
            while (!kbhit())
            {
                if (CIFX_NO_ERROR != (lRet = xChannelIORead(hChannel,
                    0, 0, sizeof(abRecvData),
                    abRecvData,
                    IO_WAIT_TIMEOUT)))
                {
                    printf("Error reading IO Data area!\r\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("IORead Data:");
                    //DumpData(abRecvData, sizeof(abRecvData));
                    if (CIFX_NO_ERROR != (lRet = xChannelIOWrite(hChannel,
                        0, 0, sizeof(abRecvData),
                        abRecvData,
                        IO_WAIT_TIMEOUT)))
                    {
                        printf("Error writing to IO Data area!\r\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("IOWrite Data:");
                        //DumpData(abSendData, sizeof(abSendData));
                        /* Create new output data */
                        memset(abSendData, ulCycle + 1, sizeof(abSendData));
                    }
                }
            }
#endif
```

Are there any ways to solve this error. Tq.

Comment: Did you look at the error message?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asked did not read their error message.

Comment: @JamesKPolk i did looked at it and i tried changing the `kbhit` to `_kbhit`. but once i make the changes my whole program showing alot of linkage errors.

Answer (score 3):

"Are there any ways to solve this error" - Yes. The solution is *literally* part of the error message: "Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _kbhit".

Comment: @anonymous5671 and would you care to enlighten us as to the contents of this "other message"?

Comment: sure. it shows `Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _xDriverOpen referenced in function _wmain`

Comment: @anonymous5671 - So now you have a new problem. Previously you had a compiler error, now you have a linker error. To solve it, link the library providing the required function.